# Which one to use here? Did not or had not?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, past-simple

Friend: •does something stupid•

Me: I did not expect you'd do this.

OR

I had not expected you to do this

I think
the act of expecting is happening before the reference point which is when the other person did whatever he did. Literally, it would be 'I had not expected you to do this'.

Comment: Assuming you make the first sentence *you'd **do** this* (it might have been a typo), then both sentences are grammatical.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo